# Search for flattened field existence in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm storing an arbitrary nested object as a flattened field "_meta" which contains various information related to a product.
Here is the mapping for that field:

```
"mappings": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
            "_meta": {
                "type": "flattened"
            },
            ...
```

So when trying to search for:

```
{
    "query": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "_meta.user"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to retrieve all documents that have that field populated. I get zero hits, although if I search for a particular document, I can see that at least one document has that field populated:

```
"user": {
  "origin_title": "some title",
  "origin_title_en": "some other title",
  "address": "some address",
  "performed_orders_count": 0,
  "phone": "some phone",
  "name": "some name",
  "tariff": null,
  "proposal_image_background_color": null
},
```

So how exactly does searching through a flattened data field work?
Why I'm not getting any results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

It is because of the way [`flattened` fields work](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/flattened.html).

In your case:

```json
{
    "_meta":{
        "user": {
            "name": "some name"
        }
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch available representation are:

```json
{
    "_meta": ["some name"],
    "_meta.user.name": "some name"
}
```

## To reproduce

For the set up:

```json
PUT /74025685/
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "_meta":{
        "type": "flattened"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"74025685"}}
{"_meta":{"user": "some user"}}
{"index":{"_index":"74025685"}}
{"_meta":{"user": null, "age": 10}}
{"index":{"_index":"74025685"}}
{"_meta":{"user": ""}}
{"index":{"_index":"74025685"}}
{"_meta":{"user": {"username": "some user"}}}
```

This query is going to find 2 records:

```json
GET 74025685/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_meta": {
        "value": "some user"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This one, is only going to match the first documents:

```json
GET 74025685/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_meta.user": {
        "value": "some user"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And so for the exist query:

This one will only return the last doc.

```json
GET 74025685/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "_meta.user.username"
    }
  }
}
```

Whereas this one os going to return the 1st and 3rd:

```json
GET 74025685/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "_meta.user"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So in other words, I can only search for leaf key/values inside a flattened fields data type?

Comment: That's what I believe indeed